# MarkLogic 8, forgot user name I used. What can I do?

Tags: authentication, marklogic

I just installed MarkLogic 8 and forgot user name I used. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Since you just installed, *if you haven't done anything that would bother you to lose*, it might be simplest to blow it away and start again. Uninstall MarkLogic, then remove the data directory (`rm -rf /var/opt/MarkLogic` on Linux), then reinstall.

Again, this is only if you haven't started loading up data, setting up apps, etc. If you have, go with DALDEI's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical and legal authority over the system, you can copy off the Forest directories (except security),  re-install from scratch then re-attach the data.  Most of the metadata will still be intact and as long as you have the *new* admin password you can patch up the parts that are not.

That is if you havent already customized a complex system - the hardest part to restore will be the objects in the Security database, those will be lost.
( users, permissions, roles etc)   There is also the group and database configurations - those are not secured in the same ( they are stored in XML files on disk) so if you have system OS root access its likely possible to reconstruct most of the configuration data as well.

If this is a mission critical system I suggest contacting support, there are some methods for recovery of most of your data if done very carefully and if you have physical access and the data is otherwise unencrypted and accessable.